# Extract serial number from .pfx file using PHP

Tags: php, openssl

Is there a simple way using OpenSSL to extract the serial number of a certificate using PHP?

I've tried converting the .pfx file to a .pem file using an openssl command, but I'm wondering if it's possible purely inside PHP.

I'm currently able to read the serial number from a .pem/.crt file, but not from a .pfx file.

Thank you for any help given

Answer (score 0):

You may use [chilkat php extension](https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/cert_load_from_pfx.asp) and use following code:

```
include("chilkat_9_5_0.php");
$cert = new CkCert();

$pfxFilename = '/your/path/to.pfx';
$pfxPassword = 'test';

$success = $cert->LoadPfxFile($pfxFilename,$pfxPassword);
if ($success != true) {
    print $cert->lastErrorText() . "\n";
    exit;
}

print 'Serial Number:' . $cert->serialNumber() . "\n";
```